# I need help consolidating my functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project right now where I have a drop down and in the drop down there are many links. So what I am doing now is what I have below for each button. There are a lot of them.

```
$(".button1").click(function() {
    $(".contentContainer").load( "pages/functional_components_controlPanels.html" );
});
```

Will someone point out a more graceful way to do this to reduce my code down please? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what's similar and different between the buttons and their click handlers, as you need to find common patterns between them. Posting one is not going to help us see a pattern between many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data-drive your code instead, using attributes on your button (or dropdown options, or links or whatever elements you like):

Example Html (with `data-` attributes for any extra values you need):

```
<input type="button" data-content="pages/functional_components_controlPanels.html"/>
```

Sample Code (makes use of `data-` attributes):

```
// Apply this only to inputs with data-content attributes (could be any filter you like)
$("input[data-content]").click(function() {

    // Extract values you need from attribute on the clicked item
    var content = $(this).data('content');

    // use the values to make decisions, specify parameters etc
    $(".contentContainer").load(content);
});
```

Plugins, like unobtrusive ajax, use `data-` attributes, so they do not have to be hard-wired to elements.

Attributes starting with the `data-` prefix are an allowed standard for browsers and are valid HTML (other attribute names are not always valid, so use the `data-` prefix).